# Creating SMTP client tosend report to list of mails in UNIX

Tags: shell, email, unix

I want to create a Unix application based to be SMTP client i should have a configuration file containing parameters like timeout , sending repeat , mail list ,... there will be a directory with path defined in configuration file this directory will have files the application should loop the mail list sending the files in directory as attachments . 
I am kinda new so thanks for any help 
for the script i'm using :

```
. var.properties
for i in MAIL* ;do
echo test | mail -s `echo $SUBJECT` `echo $i`
done
```

but the output is + i need to know how to attach files i use -f and -a but not working 
You must specify direct recipients with -s, -c, or -b.

Comment: Sorry, this question is far too broad. It basically asks: "teach me everything about shell programming".

Comment: i can send an e-mail using command line and i can make a properties file i can also run it in the script i have problem in making the mail list looping through it to send the files attached to each mail in the list

Comment: Ah, so you already did some implementation. May I suggest that you add your code to the question, so that we can see what the issue is?

Comment: Sorry, can you please add that to the question, not inside comments, so that it is readable and all information is together? There is an `edit` button below the question...

Answer (score 0):

You need a `do` to start the `for` loop body (and a `done` to close it).

```
for i in MAIL* ; do
  echo test | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$i"
done
```

(Those `` `echo $foo` `` things are not a good idea, but do keep the variables inside double-quotes to avoid problems if they contain spaces.)